# Ionic slides card horizontal

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3, ion-slides

I need help. When I start to slide on the left my 2nd card to nth is not showing.

```
<ion-content>
 <div class="container">
    <ion-slides pager slidesPerView="1.1">
        <ion-slide *ngFor="let subject of cardData">
            <ion-card class="cardList">
                <ion-card-header>
                    <ion-card-title>
                        <h1> {{subject.title}}</h1>
                    </ion-card-title>
                </ion-card-header>
                <ion-card-content>
                    <h1> {{subject.description}}</h1>
                </ion-card-content>
            </ion-card>
        </ion-slide>
    </ion-slides>
 </div>
</ion-content>
```

Am I missing Something?

[Screenshot Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yzeJg.png)

Comment: Could you add the ts files please ?

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is in this `prop`: `slidesPerView="1.1"` the documentation establish:

> slidesPerView | number |  Slides per view. Slides visible at the same time. Default: 1.

As you set in your `slidesPerView="1.1"` that is why in your image you can see like the one slide and a little more from the another one. If you want to prevent this behavior then remove that `prop` or change it for a int value

Comment: This is not the case. the slidesperview 1.1 is working. I just want the user see the portion of the next card that's why i used the 1.1.